# My video header wont't play when the page loads

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

I have a video in my header, however, it will only play once you click on the home link in the menu to go to the /index.html. It will not play when the page first loads. I have also tested to see if manually entering /index.html at the end of the url works, it does not. The code I am using to play the video is:

```
<video autoplay loop>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="images/untitled.mp4" />
    <source type="video/webm" src="images/untitled.webm" />
</video>
```

And my website is http://richardgao.5gbfree.com (source code can be checked)

How do I get the video to play automatically when I first load the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tested it in chrome? for chrome you need to switch off sound:

```
<video autoplay muted loop> ... </video>
```

and at least on some versions of safari autoplay doesn't work at all. you might start your vid using jquery, something like:

```
<video id="video" ...> ... </video>

$(document).ready() {
    $('#video').play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried mute, but the video doesn't have sound anyways, so it didn't work. And yes, I am playing ti on Chrome

Comment: you have to mute videos without sound too. check the output in your console, obviously there's a problem with the headers:

    Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://embed.waze.com/iframe?zoom=15&lat=44.215057&lon=-78.150151&pin=1': 'ALLOW ALL' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.